# AngularJS - ngModel cannot be assigned to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is very common one. I saw many different cases of people with similar question to mine, but I still does not have my answer.

**[My goals]**
I want to implement a standalone directive to encapsulate div consisting of label(span) and value(input). There are some specifics that worth mentioning here:

1. My directive aims to preserve the value of the "input" into my page controller score which is an ancestor of the scope my directive works with. Hence with the proper amount of ".$parent" I can access the desired scope for my ngModel assignment.
2. My directive does not know the name of the placeholder it shall use to preserve the user input as. This placeholder is coming as an HTML property to my directive.

**[My approach]**
I am using the directive compile phase to manipulate the directive's HTML (mainly adding properties to directive's template HTML). In the pre-link phase I want manipulate the scope that directive is using in order to add the directive's placeholder to my desired scope and assign it some default value if needed. (I guess I can achieve that with ng-init instead of messing with the scopes, but i believe that is irrelevant to my question).

**[What I did]**
As I explained above I have a function (determinePlaceholderName()) that returns a string which is the exact value I want to assign to ngModel. For example:

```
$parent.$parent.$parent.placeHolderName
```

I want to assign that function to input's ng-model attribute assuming that Angular will treath it as an expression, evaluate it and produce what I expected. Here is how I assign the ng-model property:

```
compile: function(cElem, cAttrs) {
    //Some non relevant code here ....

    $(cElem[0]).find("div input").attr("ng-model", "determinePlaceholderName()");
}
```

Basically what I expect is this to be treated like:

```
$(cElem[0]).find("div input").attr("ng-model", "$parent.$parent.$parent.placeHolderName");
```

**[About determinePlaceholderName()]**
This function I define in the link function of my directive:

```
link: function ($scope) {

        $scope.constructValuePlaceholderName = function() {
            //Some logic here.

            return result;
}
```

**[My Problem]**
And finally what my problem is.
Angular result in an error explaining to me that

```
<input ng-model="myFunc()">
```

is non-assignable expression as documented.

**[My Question]**
How can I dinamically set ngModel if function assignment is forbidden by Angular??

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Its nice to see a question where the OP has spent time explaining his problem. Good job dude! +1

Comment: Hi Milen,
I think you should more into scopes and inheritance '$parent.$parent.$parent' should be hardly accepted, although I can see that you try to use jquery. IMHO if you want do use jquery use just jquery, if you want to use angular do it angular way. I'm happy to help/provide you with working examples of your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TojgLNx3TUbmszhfs8Ui?p=preview

Using isolated scope, you can pass the name of the model, and the directive itself is not aware of the scope the model actually sits on or its name, but is able to use it as is and give it to ngModel.

The plunker also provides alternatives in case you don't want to use isolate scope or want to use a function.

Comment: Hi m8, thanks for the answer and sorry for my late response. Actually what I asked is kinda different from what you propose. However your idea is nice and working work around of my problem. Instead of calling the function to bind the ngModel, one can just manage it the way you did it. Since I didn't manage to find better answer to my problem, I will accept your answer. However the bad part about it is that it demands that your directive creates a scope (the isolate scope is still a scope) and that is kinda restrictive.

Comment: You don't have to use an isolate scope or a scope at all, I updated the plunker with more examples.